# How can I do the correction of this demonstration in the euclidian space?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

[Geometrically deriving Lorentz transformation from Minkowski diagram](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/237313/geometrically-deriving-lorentz-transformation-from-minkowski-diagram)

I read this and didn't understand the part of the hiperbolic counterpart correction. I do understand the invariant space-time is not the euclidian distance and some type of correction has to be made, but why is that replacing

> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\beta^{2}}}\text{ by }\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^{2}}}\ ?$$

Where does this come from and how is it calculated?

Answer (score 0):

In Euclidean space, where $\Delta s^2=\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2$ (which is associated with a circle),
the slope of a segment is $m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\tan\phi$
and
$$\cos\phi=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta s}=\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{\Delta x^2 +\Delta y^2}}
=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta x\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\right)^2}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}.$$

---

In Minkowski spacetime, where $\Delta \tau^2=\Delta t^2 - \Delta y^2$ (which is associated with a hyperbola),
the slope of a segment (called the [dimensionless-]velocity) is $\beta=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}=\tanh\theta$...

$$\cosh\theta=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\phantom{\hspace{15em}}$$
...
**I'll let you finish the calculation for $\cosh\theta$ (called the time-dilation factor).**

---

By the way...

On a position-vs-time graph [a Galilean spacetime], where $\Delta \tau^2=\Delta t^2 - 0\Delta y^2$ (which is associated with a Galilean-circle [a hyperplane]),
the slope of a segment is $\frac{v}{c_{ref}}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}=\mbox{tang }\eta$
( using *I.M. Yaglom's Galilean tangent function $\mbox{tang }\eta\equiv \eta$ and Galilean cosine function $\mbox{cosg }\eta\equiv 1$)

and
$$\mbox{cosg }\eta=\frac{ADJ}{HYP}=\frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{\Delta t^2 -0\Delta y^2}}
=\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta t\sqrt{1-0\left(\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta t}\right)^2}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-0\left(\frac{v}{c_{ref}} \right)^2}}=1$$
the Galilean time-dilation factor, which is 1.

- "A Simple Non-Euclidean Geometry and Its Physical Basis" (I.M. Yaglom)

(See also my visualization:
robphy's spacetime diagrammer for relativity v.8e-2021 (time upward)
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/emqe6uyzha  )